# XStream: Keep parts of the XML as XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have the following XML:

```
<patient>
    <name>Mr. Sick</name>
    <report>
        <paragraph><bold>Conclusion</bold>text...</paragraph>
    </report>
</patient>
```

I would like to convert this to an instance of class Patient like this:

```
Class Patient {
    String name = "Mr. Sick";
    String report = "<paragraph><bold>Conclusion</bold>text...</paragraph>";
}
```

Is it possible to use XStream to convert only part of the XML and keep the report field in XML format? How can it be done?

Comment: You could do this using a JAXB implementation (Metro, EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe), with the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: Thanks. Although I did not use this solution, it helped to find the answer. A search on @XmlAnyElement in combination with XStream gave me enough information to get me going again. I posted my answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by creating an Convertor implementation, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622863/intercepting-xstream-while-parsing-xml). My solution for the problem is as follows:

Patient.java

```
public class Patient {
    String name;
    Report report;
}
```

Report.java

```
public class Report {
    public String report;
}
```

An implementation of a Convertor for XStream

```
public class ReportConverter implements Converter { 

    @Override 
    public boolean canConvert(Class classs) { 
        System.out.println("canConvert: " + classs.getName());
        return classs.equals(Report.class); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, 
            MarshallingContext context) {
        // not used in this example
    } 

    // goes recursive through all the nodes in <report>
    String getNodeAsText(HierarchicalStreamReader reader) {
        String result;
        result = "<" + reader.getNodeName() + ">" + reader.getValue();
        while (reader.hasMoreChildren() ) {
            reader.moveDown();
            result += getNodeAsText(reader);
            reader.moveUp();
            result += reader.getValue();
        }
        result += "</" + reader.getNodeName() + ">";
        return result;
    }

    @Override 
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, 
            UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Report xReport = new Report();
        xReport.report = reader.getValue();
        while (reader.hasMoreChildren() ) {
            reader.moveDown();
            xReport.report += getNodeAsText(reader);
            reader.moveUp();
            xReport.report += reader.getValue();
        }
        return xReport; 
    } 
}
```

Example use of the convertor with XStream

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.registerConverter(new ReportConverter());
xStream.alias("patient", Patient.class);
xStream.alias("report", Report.class);
String xml = "<patient><name>Mr. Sick</name><report><paragraph>" +
        "some text here<bold>Conclusion</bold>text...</paragraph>" +
        "<sdf>hello world</sdf></report></patient>";
Patient patient = (Patient)xStream.fromXML(xml);
System.out.println("patient.name: " + patient.name);
System.out.println("patient.report: " + patient.report.report);
```

Output

```
patient: Mr. Sick
patient.report: <paragraph>some text here<bold>Conclusion</bold>text...
    ...</paragraph><sdf>hello world</sdf>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the answer for the question asked but I suggest an alternative that could maybe help.

You should probably escaping the content of the `report` field. This will help you avoid invalid xml which can be very problematic at unmarshal time.

Here is one simple way to do that (using the commons libray from apache [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)):

```
class Patient {
   String name = "Mr. Sick";
   String report = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(
         "<paragraph><bold>Conclusion</bold>text...</paragraph>");

  // report = "&lt;paragraph&gt;&lt;bold&gt;Conclusion&lt;/bold&gt;text...&lt;/paragraph&gt;"
}
```

Comment: That would work if I start with the Patient class instance and then create the XML. I need it the other way around. I have a database full with problematic XML messages. I like to convert them to a java class as shown in my example.

Comment: Care to show us what you've got for code in this particular situation?

Answer (score 2):

Better version of getNodeAsText() that includes the attributes of each node:

`private String getNodeAsText(HierarchicalStreamReader reader) {`

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append("<")
   .append(reader.getNodeName());

for (int i = 0; i < reader.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
  String name = reader.getAttributeName(i);
  String value = reader.getAttribute(i);
  str.append(" ")
     .append(name)
     .append("=\"")
     .append(value)
     .append("\"");
}
str.append(">")
   .append(reader.getValue());

while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
  reader.moveDown();
  str.append(getNodeAsText(reader));
  reader.moveUp();
  str.append(reader.getValue());
}
str.append("</")
   .append(reader.getNodeName())
   .append(">");

return str.toString();
```

}